# Android: onActivityResult() local data is missing

Tags: java, android, android-activity, start-activity

I have two activities(Activity1 and Activity2). Activity1 starts Activity2 for get some data. Whenever I back to Activity1 onCreate method is runing before the onActivityResult().And all data is gone. Why onCreate method is runing second time and  data is missing?

You can check example code at below to see sample scenario. In this case a value of var1 should be 5 in onActivityResult method but its 0.

```
public class MainActivity1 extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    TextView textView1;
    Button button1;
    int var1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                var1 = 5;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2
            }
        });
    }

    // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 2) {
            String message = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            textView1.setText("value =" + var1);

        }
    }

}


public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText editText1;
    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String message=editText1.getText().toString();
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);

                setResult(2,intent);

                finish();//finishing activity
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Settings > Developer Options there is a setting called "Don't keep activities". Make sure this isn't enabled, or the activity would be destroyed as soon as you start the second activity, and you would be recreating the first activity upon returning to it.

Comment: @user3269905 while in background, the first Activity could be destroyed by the Android OS anyway, in this case you will face this problem again. You should implement better the logic of your method.

Comment: Soffritti got right ... do a simple check: start second activity, change phone's orientation, back to first activity ... this is hack not a solution

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. You're saving a String in the intent.
Then in the `onActivityResult` method you retrieve the String from the intent, and then set the TextView's text to `"value =" var1`, but you didn't load `var1` from the Intent.

You should save the value `var1` in the intent in `MainActivity2`, and then retrieve it from the intent in the `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: Yes he should do that. But please give better instructions. Save? Use putExtra! `Intent intent=new Intent();` ? Better use getIntent() or the var will not be there.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Do you mean I shouldnt left behind me the data when I go to an activity I should take them with me and when I return I should bring them back. Did I get it right? Even if have a lot of data still is this the best practice? @Pierfrancesco Soffritti

Comment: No, the logical steps are: 1. Start an activity for result 2. Do some operations in this activity 3. Save the result of those operations in the intent (with putExtra ()) 4. Finish the activity 5. In the onActivityResult method of the first activity get the result you saved in the intent